# Ruby MySQL/Gem issue Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7, gem

I'm trying to use mysql for RoR on windows 7. for that I install mysql gem as follow.

```
PS D:\Apps> gem install mysql
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32...
```

Now after that when i try to add mysql to gem list then i get following error:

```
PS D:\Apps> gem mysql
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command mysql
```

I can see that mysql gem is there in gem folder but gem is not allowing me to add it to gem file. any comments/help please.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, the mysql gem requires the presence of the `mysql` binary somewhere in the path. This is the mysql client, which the gem uses for many of its operations.